# obtaining the clientID of the user assigned Managed Identity

Tags: azure-functions, azure-managed-identity

I have an azure function with a user assigned managed identity.
I have not found a way to obtain the clientID of this managedIdentity from within the azure function app c# code.

Is this possible?

Comment: you could always create an app setting for that. could be done while you re provisioning the function app itself.

Comment: Please provide us the code you tried and the result/error you're facing!

Comment: Thomas: I have created an app setting, but i have to manually add the clientID of the managed identity. HariKrishnaRajoli-MT: I have no code to show as i have not found an example of how this might be accomplished, which is why i was asking here.

Comment: Are you assigning the user managed identity from IaaC (script/ arm/ bicep etc.) ? you could set the app settings automatically while doing that.

Comment: This is exactly what i am doing Thomas. I was hoping there was a way of directly getting the Managed Identity, besides requiring configuration of an app setting. it does not look like there is however. thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you tell why you need the clientId?